# How to assign value from an Object to an element in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, object

I have these data fetched from an `API` call:
[image]

I want to show these data to select option elements so I have this line of codes in my AJAX script file:

```
$.each($(value.routes), function(index, route){
     $('.searchable-select').append('\
     <option value="'+route+'"> From: '+route+'</option>\
     ');
});
```

How can I set the option value as 1 and 2 and the string ("From:...") as the text from this object?

Comment: add sample array

Comment: the sample array is on the picture..

Comment: That's not an array but an object with numeric keys hence the first parameter of the callback should be named "key" or "property" because it's not an index. Then just use the key/property instead of `route` for the value

Comment: My bad.. my question is updated

Comment: You want to iterate the `routes` and pass the `data` to the `<option value="${index}">${valueString}</option>` and append it on the `<select>` right?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen Yes. It is.

Comment: @JayMarz I already post my answer, just check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate the routes object, you can use the $.each of jquery.

Codes look like this.

```js
var routes = {
 1: "From Davao Del Sur (Phillipines) ...",
 2: "From Soccsksargen (Phillipines)"
}

var select = '<select>';
$.each(routes, function(index, route) {
 select += '<option value="'+ index +'">'+ route +'</option>';
})
select += '</select>';

$('#demo').html(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to do [String splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var route = "From: Davao Del Sur (Phillipines) - To: Soccsksargen (Phillipines)";
var from = route.split("From: ")[1].split(" - ")[0];

console.log(from);

// How it works:
// Split String into array by using "From: " as seperator:
var array1 = route.split("From: ");
console.log(array1);
// take second element from array
console.log(array1[1]);
// split the element into another array using " - " as seperator:
var array2 = array1[1].split(" - ");
console.log(array2);
// take first element from array
console.log(array2[0]);

// done
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to split the string. The string value `"From: Davao Del Sur (Phillipines) - To: Soccsksargen (Phillipines)"` has to be put as text inside `option` element and the numbers 1 and 2 as its values.